# Rails Chatting application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, websocket, faye

I want to make `Rails Chat` like application and I am going through some problems

I went to this website [Realtime Mini-Chat with Rails and Faye](http://www.sitepoint.com/realtime-mini-chat-rails-faye/) 
and I have downloaded the source code

After removing some errors, I got the index page where you have to login via fb or twitter, but when someone clicks Fb link it **throws an error**

> "The parameter app_id is required"

Can anybody help me with this problem?

Comment: You have to setup your app on **developers.facebook.com**. Google **The parameter app_id is required** you will get results related to the problem.

Comment: Following link might be helpful.
http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/facebook-graph-api-using-omniauth-facebook-and-koala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i got it,
its with the gem 'omniauth-facebook' gem, 
for that i have to register on developers.facebook.com and register their
Facebook need